# Mobx Loading wrapper React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, react-dom, mobx-react

## Question

- What's the best way to write a common component which will be used across projects for handling loading view using Mobx, react tech stack
- Let's assume we are making an API call to get product list,

  > When apiStatus is fetching, we will render loadingview
  >
  > When apiStatus is success, we will render successView i.e List of products
  >
  > When apiStatus is failed due to server error or internet failure, we will render failureview with retry button

### Proposed solution 1:

```
// LoadingWrapperWithFailure.js

@observer
class LoadingWrapperWithFailure extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { apiStatus, apiError, children, onRetry } = this.props;

    switch (apiStatus) {
      case API_FETCHING:
        // Loading state
        return <LoadingView loaderProps={loaderProps} />;
      case API_SUCCESS:
        // Success state
        return children;
      case API_FAILED:
        // Failed state
        return <FailureView onRetry={onRetry} apiError={apiError} />;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

```
// Usage

@observer
class ProductList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {
      apiStatus,
      apiError,
      productList,
      onRetryApi
    } = this.props.productStore;
    return (
      <LoadingWrapperWithFailure
        apiStatus={apiStatus}
        apiError={apiError}
        onRetry={onRetryApi}
      >
        <SuccessView>
          {/* Renders productList when apicall is success */}
        </SuccessView>
      </LoadingWrapperWithFailure>
    );
  }
}
> Note: apiStatus, apiError, productList are mobx observable variables
```

### Proposed solution 2:

```
// LoadingWrapperWithFailure.js

@observer
class LoadingWrapperWithFailure extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { apiStatus, apiError, renderSuccessUI: RenderSuccessUI, onRetry } = this.props;

    switch (apiStatus) {
      case API_FETCHING:
        // Loading state
        return <LoadingView loaderProps={loaderProps} />;
      case API_SUCCESS:
        // Success state
        return <RenderSuccessUI />;
      case API_FAILED:
        // Failed state
        return <FailureView onRetry={onRetry} apiError={apiError} />;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

```
// Usage

@observer
class ProductList extends React.Component {

  renderSuccessUI = observer(() => {
    const { productList } = this.props.productStore
    return (
      <SuccessView>
          {/* Renders productList when apicall is success */}
      </SuccessView>
    )
  })

  render() {
    const {
      apiStatus,
      apiError,
      onRetryApi
    } = this.props.productStore;
    return (
      <LoadingWrapperWithFailure
        apiStatus={apiStatus}
        apiError={apiError}
        onRetry={onRetryApi}
        renderSuccessUI={this.renderSuccessUI}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

What's the best way?

Why it is the best way?

Are there any other better ways of achieving the above functionality?

Pls, comment if you need more info. TIA.